# Unable to run oracle report contains attached library

Tags: oracle, oc4j, oas

Oracle Application server 10g
Oracle report is using a library. When I'm attaching library it asked me if I want to remove path.
It works with option "NO" - not removing library, but it does not work if I select "YES". and I got the Unable to run report error.

although I already set the library path in the following places:-

- REGEDIT FORMS_PATH to C:\DevSuiteHome_1\forms;
- REGEDIT REPORTS_PATH to C:\DevSuiteHome_1\forms;
- default.env file FORMS_PATH to C:\DevSuiteHome_1\forms;

Comment: you need to provide more details, what's the full error message that you're getting?

Comment: I got this error REP-52251: Cannot get output of job ID 2834 you requested on Wed Mar 28 13:25:18 GMT+04:00 2012.<P>REP-51026: No output for job 2834

Comment: is the library present on the application server, the same place where the reports are present?

Comment: Yes, in the same folder contains the reports and forms

Comment: Thank you for your help, actually in the Forms_path registry there were many paths when I set the libaray path in the first of them, the report run probably, thanks

Comment: you're welcome, I've moved both comments to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to confirm:

- Ensure the library is present in the same directory as the reports - without the path info,  the library is picked from the same location as the reports
- Ensure the environment variables are set correctly so that the Reports engine is looking at the right directory to pick up the libraries